# Creating multiple dimensional list to replace subseting - Is it worth?

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, runtime, subset

### Basic idea:

As said before, is a good idea to substitute subsisting a data frame, for a multidimensional list?

I have a function that need to generate a subset from a quite big data frame close to 30 thousand times. Thus, creating a 4 dimensional list, will give me *instant* access to the subset, without loosing time generating it.

However, I don't know how R treats this objects, so I would like you opinion on it.

---

### More concrete example if needed:

What I was trying to do is to use the inputation method of KNN. Basically, the algorithm says that the value found as outliers has to be replaced with K(K in a number, it could be 1,2,3...) closest neighbor. The neighbor in this example are the rows with the same attributes in the first 4 columns. And, the closed neighbors are the one with the smallest difference between the fifth column. If it is not clear what I said, please still consider reading the code, because, I found it hard to describe in words.

This are the objects

```
#create a vector with random values
values <- floor(runif(5e7, 0, 50)
possible.outliers <- floor(runif(5e7, 0, 10000)

#use this values, in a mix way, create a data frame
df <- data.frame( sample(values), sample(values), sample(values),
                  sample(values), sample(values), sample(possible.outliers)

#all the values greater then 800 will be marked as outliers
df$isOutlier = df[,6] > 800
```

This is the function which will be used to replace the outliers

```
#with the generated data frame, do this function
#Parameter:
#   *df: The entire data frame from the above
#   *vector.row: The row that was marked that contains an outlier. The outlier will be replaced with the return of this function
#   *numberK: The number of neighbors to take into count.
# !Very Important: Consider that, the last column, the higher the 
#                  difference between their values, less attractive 
#                  they are for an inputation.
foo <- function(df, vector.row, numberK){
    #find the neighbors 
    subset = df[ vector.row[1] == df[,1] & vector.row[2] == df[,2] &
                 vector.row[3] == df[,3] & vector.row[4] == df[,4] , ]

    #taking the "distance" from the rows, so It can find which are the
    # closest neighbors 
    subset$distance = subset[,5] - vector.row[5]

    #not need to implement
    "function that find the closest neighbors from the distance on subset"

    return (mean(ClosestNeighbors))
}
```

So, the function runtime is quite big. For this reason, I am searching for alternatives and I thought that, maybe, if I replace the subsisting for something like this:

```
list[[" Levels COl1 "]][[" Levels COl2 "]]
    [[" Levels COl3 "]][[" Levels COl4 "]]
```

What this should do is an instant access to the subset, instead of generating it all the time inside the function.

---

Is it a reasonable idea? I`am a noob in R.
If you did not understood what is written, or would like something to be explained in more detain or in other words, please tell me, because I know it is not the most direct question.

Comment: It is possible to create many-dimensional structures in R, especially using matrices. However, using R for anything resembling a star-schema is highly inefficient. If this is a short-term project, your approach will give you a 'quick-win', but I would avoid that in a repetitive/production environment and move it into a database where you can query in MDX.

Comment: could you please tell me a little bit about what you mean with *move it into a database where you can query in MDX*? Is it something outside R, am I rigth? But, are you saying it has integration with R?